Negative Derivative and Function
I have a function,
$f(x) = x^2 - x \sin(x) - \cos(x)$
I was looking forward to graph this function using calculus properties.
So, I took the derivate of $f(x)$.
$$\frac{d[f(x)]}{dx}= f'(x) = 2x-x\cos(x)$$
$$f'(x)= x(2-\cos(x))$$
Now, $1 ≤2-\cos(x)≤3$ and I concluded that if
$x> 0, f'(x)> 0 $; if
$x<0, f'(x)< 0$.
However, when I plotted the graph, $f(x)$ is actually increasing even when $x < 0$, despite $f'(x)< 0$.
Please guide upon what's the error, and why is this function behaving so.

Plotting a function is usually harder than taking its derivative, so maybe check the validity of your plot.

Your conclusion is right. Here is the graph:


@X K H Yes,the graph is correct but why is it increasing in (0,-∞) while it's derivative is negative?

@OmkarDeshmukh Well, it is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$, so no contradiction. (coincide with $f'(x)<0$ when $x<0$)
